# using pregmatch to only match the whole key word not part of it

Tags: php, preg-match

not sure how to go about this.

But i need to check part of my url for a matching word.

The problem is that it is finding part of the word in another URL and i dont want that.

I only want it to give a result if it find the exact word.

So i have this:

```
if (preg_match('@news?@i',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    // match
}
```

This gives a match for the URL of /news.php but it also gives a match if the URL is /newlyupdated

Any help?

Comment: `preg_match('@^news$@', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);` But exact word ('news') won't match 'news.php', so you would have to add `.php` to the regular expression.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what _should_ be matched?  `/news, /news.php, /notnews /path/to/news` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be looking for the [word boundary anchor, `\b`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php). A pattern like `@\bfoo\b@` will match `foo`, but not `food`.

Periods and slashes act as word separators:

```
php > var_dump(preg_match('@\bnews?\b@i', 'foo/newlyupdated.php'));
int(0)
php > var_dump(preg_match('@\bnews?\b@i', 'foo/news.php'));
int(1)
php > var_dump(preg_match('@\bnews?\b@i', 'foo/new.php'));
int(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [parse_url](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) instead of a regular expression.  parse_url is more reliable and allows you to match against **just** your path.

```
<?php

  $myURL = parse_url( $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] );
  if ($myURL['path'] == 'news.php') {
      // Match
  }
```